# has_many :through association through two different associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have four model classes:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
  has_many :personal_blogs
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events, :as => :event_producer
end

class PersonalBlog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events, :as => :event_producer
end

class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event_producer, :polymorphic => true
end
```

I want to find all of the events for a particular group. I figure this is a has_many :through association, but how do I specify a has_many on Group that finds all events in the projects **or** personal_blogs of a group? I could, of course, specify two associations and concatenate the results, but then I have to re-sort, limit, condition, etc. in Ruby, which could potentially be a performance nightmare with many events. I'd like to do this within ActiveRecord to avoid such a nightmare.

Answer (score 5):

You could define a method in the Group class like next:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
  has_many :personal_blogs

  def events
    Event.find(:all, :conditions => ['(type = ? AND event_producer_id IN (?)) OR (type = ? AND event_producer IN (?))', 'project', project_ids, 'personal_blog', personal_blog_ids])
  end
end
```

If you don't like SQL like the previous one, it's always possible to use Single Table Inheritance. This solution depends on your [classes attributes and behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555668/single-table-inheritance-and-where-to-use-it-in-rails), but will allow you to use a "has_many through" association.

Comment: This doesn't actually work for me, because I need to restrict the search to a particular group. The reference to the group is polymorphic across a join, making the SQL considerably more complex.

Comment: This is actually restricted by Group. Notice that I'm using "project_ids" and "personal_blog_ids" collections that are already filtering out the projects and personal_blogs that don't belongs to the actual group.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
  has_many :personal_blogs

  def all_events
    projects.events + personal_blogs.events
  end
end
```

Comment: "I could, of course, specify two associations and concatenate the results, but then I have to re-sort, limit, condition, etc. in Ruby, which could potentially be a performance nightmare with many events. I'd like to do this within ActiveRecord to avoid such a nightmare."

Answer (score 0):

If you need an association that you can preload you could specify a custom 'from' query that includes the group id with the event.

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
  has_many :personal_blogs
  has_many :events, -> {from(<<~SQL)}
    (
      SELECT DISTINCT e.*, g.id as group_id
      FROM events e
        LEFT JOIN projects p ON p.event_id = e.id
        LEFT JOIN personal_blogs pb ON pb.event_id = e.id
        INNER JOIN groups g ON g.id IN (p.group_id, pb.group_id)
    ) as events
  SQL
end
```