# Refer to similar associated models with a common name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, polymorphic-associations

I have these models:

```
class Bill < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :calls
  has_many :text_messages
end

class Call < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bill
end

class TextMessage < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bill
end
```

Now, in my domain calls and text messages are both "the same kind of thing" -- i.e., they're both "bill items". So I'd like `some_bill.bill_items` to return all calls *and* text messages associated with that bill. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new model, `BillItems` and insert it into your relationship chain. Then you could access all bill items collectively or individual call/text messages via a has many through relationship. Another possibility would be to look into [single table inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555668/single-table-inheritance-and-where-to-use-it-in-rails).

Comment: what do you mean by "insert it into your relationship chain"? So Bills would have_many BillItems, every BillItem has_one call / text_message (via polymorphic associations?), and Bills have_many :calls / :text_messages :through => :bill_item?