# Creating a subset of a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model in Rails representing stores

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
```

A boolean field "draft" in this model determines if the record is active or if it's just a draft.
I'm using acts_as_xapian to do searches in my application and it receives a model where the search should be performed. This part is working. However, I only want to run the search only on items that are active (draft==false)

I'm not sure how I can restrict the search on acts_as_xapian, but I could do the same by creating a new model which contains only the items from the class Store with draft==false.

Initially I thought I could use a method with a find

```
def self.active
  find :all, :conditions => {:draft => false}
end
```

but acts_as_xapian really wants a model.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a scope for that to simplify calling it:

```
named_scope :bloqueado,
  :conditions => { :bloqueado => true }
```

This means you can call the scope any time you want to find them:

```
Store.bloqueado.all
```

From a matter of style, I'd argue that your logic is inverted. Generally it's best to set boolean fields to represent a positive assertion, such as "published" instead of something akin to true meaning "not published" or draft. This gives you the logical pair "published"/"not published" instead of "draft and not published"/"not draft and not not published".

Comment: Sorry, my conditions tag made reference to the :bloqueado field, instead of :draft.
I agree with the draft/published argument. Good point.

I really need to create a new class for this. It can't look like Store.bloqueado, but rather like ViewableStore.
In other words, it needs to pass the test model_class.class == Class

Comment: It is possible to use STI to create two sub-states for a class, like PublishedStore, PreviewStore, both of which inherit from Store. This way you can retrieve, one or the other, and both, if required. Transitioning from one state to another is a bit of a hack, though, as classes aren't generally supposed to transform like that.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, what's STI?

Comment: STI is "Single Table Inheritance" which lets you define multiple classes in one table. Essentially you create a `type` column as a string, inherit the sub-classes from the parent `Store` and you should be ready to go. There are a lot of questions here that explain, for instance [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/555668/single-table-inheritance-and-where-to-use-it-in-rails).

Comment: Thanks! I think that's exactly the way to go.