# Two different profile types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, profile

Let's say you have two different categories of users with different profiles: one for music artists and one for listeners. The profiles for each have some overlapping attributes, and some different attributes. Should you have separate models for each different profile? Or should you just have a binary data column in the user table for whether the user is an artist or not? How would this be structured?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Single Table Inheritance`, which can be achieved by creating subclasses of a model.

Generate a `Profile` model with a `type:string` column ([The name can be overriden](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-set_inheritance_column)):

```
$ rails g model Profile type:string
```

Now, in `profile.rb`, subclass your model:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Common profile attributes
end

class Artist < Profile
  # Things specific to an artist profile
end

class Listener < Profile
  # Things specific to a listener profile
end
```

When you create an `Artist` or `Listener`, it'll be saved in the `profiles` table along with the type of the profile.

For example, if you do `Artist.create`, it'll be saved in the `profiles` table with `type='Artist'`.

When you fetch the record, it will be returned in its appropriate model, be it `Artist`, `Listener` or a generic `Profile`.

For more information about this technique, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555668/single-table-inheritance-and-where-to-use-it-in-rails).

[This blog post](http://code.alexreisner.com/articles/single-table-inheritance-in-rails.html) does a nice job explaining it as well.

Comment: the Artist and Listener classes both go in the Profile model? Could you point me to any sources that go into Single Table Inheritance more in depth?

Comment: also, how would I generate this from the console?

Comment: @Justin, updated answer. It is kind of disappointing how little documentation there is for this technique.

Comment: yeah I agree, that blog post is good but some of the later stuff is kind of confusing

Comment: The blog post you linked has moved, I found it [here](http://www.alexreisner.com/code/single-table-inheritance-in-rails)

Answer (score 0):

One default called Profile containing the common attributes and two others (Artistic, Listener) models with the specific attributes of each one

And in the Profile, use a field to save the type (artistic or listener)

Just my opinian.