# Association models managing classes in a "uncommon way"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, class, associations

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I have a class `List` and some other child classes that "compose" that `List` in a "uncommon way". That is, I have a `List` model with the following attributes:

```
# LIST ATTRIBUTES
id       : integer
kind_of  : string
class_id : integer
```

`kind_of` values can be "school", "house", ... and for each `kind_of` I have a class `ListSchool`, `ListHouse`, ... The `class_id` refers to the primary key of the child class of `kind_of` "school", "house", ... (so I can have multiple equal values for `class_id` but each of those referring to a particular class `ListSchool`, `ListHouse`, ... depending on the `kind_of` value).

In few words, *I would like to refer to a unique class* (the class `List`) *in order to reach all kind of child classes* (`ListSchool`, `ListHouse`, ...) *basing on an attribute value of the parent class* (the `kind_of` of the class `List`).

**How can I write the association code in order to associate those models** (maybe using `:conditions  => "kind_of = 'school'"`, `:conditions  => "kind_of = 'house'"`, ... in the association statement `has_one`)**? What do you advice about this approach of "dividing classes"?**

Comment: I assume you are working with rails 2? Can you perhaps demonstrate the purpose of such a datalayout? What kind of queries would you like to run exactly? How is the difference between ListSchool and ListHouse, for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds very much like you are looking for Single Table Inheritance (STI). Rails supports this out of the box; all you need to do is define a `type` column on the `List` class, then inherit `ListSchool` and `ListHouse` from `List`. There is no need for the `kind_of` or `class_id` columns with STI.

A web search for 'rails sti' turns up some good resources, including [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555668/single-table-inheritance-and-where-to-use-it-in-rails).