# Rails: One Inherited Comment Model vs Two Slightly Differing Comment Models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, data-modeling

I have the current (simplified) Model setup -- basically two very different models:

```
Product
- Title

Restaurant
- Title

Comment
- Message
- gps_cords (sometimes?!)
```

My goal is to let people leave comments on both `products` and `restaurants` at will based on this criteria:

1. When someone comments on a product the comment should simply have a `message`.
2. When someone comments on a restaurant the comment should have a `message` AND a `gps_cords` value.

These are what I'm considering:

Scenario 1: One big ass table w/ inheritance models

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_comments
end

class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :restaurant_comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  # message -> string
  # gps_cords -> string
  # type -> string
end

class ProductComment < Comment
  # only uses message
  belongs_to :product
end

class RestaurantComment < Comment
  # uses message AND gps_cords
  belongs_to :restaurant
end
```

Scenario 2: "Duplicate" efforts w/ two comment models

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :product_comments
end

class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :restaurant_comments
end

class ProductComment < ActiveRecord::Base
  # message -> string
  belongs_to :product
end

class RestaurantComment < ActiveRecord::Base
  # gps_cords -> string
  # message -> string
  belongs_to :restaurant
end
```

What is the correct way to model this giving consideration to:

1. Performance
2. Ability to query for "All comments"
3. "Rails way" ? (if there is)
4. Where would indexes go?

Thank you very much to the people who take time to read all of this.

Comment: You may find this question and answer useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/555668/single-table-inheritance-and-where-to-use-it-in-rails

Answer (score 0):

Use Single Table Inheritance (STI), as in the scenario 1.
Here is a link for a better understanding of it:
http://code.alexreisner.com/articles/single-table-inheritance-in-rails.html

Also, go through the question reffered in the comment above by Finbarr.

Comment: I have actually read both before posting my question.  It's not clear to me why i should use STI vs something like "commentable" (polymorphism)