# To implement independent models for different user types or not?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

So I'm building out a web app using rails and devise for authentication, and I've run into a conceptual question concerning the setup of my database.

The idea of the site is that there are two different types of users, each has its own permissions and views. For instance, when somebody registers they choose to have either user type 1 or user type 2. Then after sign up, depending on their choice, they are presented with different forms to fill in their profile, etc. The permissions come into play because type 1 users can see type 2 users but can't see other type 1 users' profiles, while type 2 users can see everyone's profiles.

Now the way I set it up, I have two separate models; one for each type of user. However, after browsing a bunch online, I've read that a lot of people only use one model, namely User, with a user-type column that identifies their type to load the appropriate resources. Before I get too far along in my approach, I'm just wondering what are the pros and cons of having multiple models for user types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use [Single Table Inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Data shared by all kinds of users
end

class Type1User < User
  # Data specific to type 1 user
end

class Type2User < User
  # Data specific to type 2 user
end
```

All these models will be saved on the `users` table, but will have a `type` column which allows you to tell them apart. `User`s returned by `find` and company will also be instances of the appropriate class.

Related:

- [Single Table Inheritance And where to use it in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/555668/512904)
- [Martin Fowler on Single Table Inheritance](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html)