# Is there a better approach to map records of children and grand children?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, dictionary, collect

I need to collect all authors in a tree like:

```
parent
|
+- child #1
|
+- child #1
|  |
|  +- grand child #1
|  |
|  +- grand child #2
|
+- child #2
...
```

(The origin post can have n childs and every child can also have m childs. Maximum depth from origin post is 2: Post - Child - Grandchild)

What is the best approach in Ruby on Rails to collect all authors (post belongs_to author)? My current approach is the following, but it seems not really performant:

```
def all_authors_in(post)
  @authors = Array.new
  @authors << post.author

  post.children.each do |child|
    @authors << child.author
    child.children.each do |grandchild| 
      @authors << grandchild.author
    end
  end

  @authors.map{|u| u.id}.uniq
end
```

Some code from the model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Post'
  has_many :children, foreign_key: :parent_id, class_name: 'Post', :dependent => :destroy
#...
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using single table inheritance for your `Post` model, but you didn't say if you rolled your own version. I'd recommend to use the [ancestry gem](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry). Then you could do something simple like this:

```
@authors = post.subtree.collect(&:author).uniq
```

Comment: Thanks. But I'm also interested in writing better code :) What do you mean with "rolled your own version"?

Comment: I mean your own version of [single table inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/555668/single-table-inheritance-and-where-to-use-it-in-rails). How is it implemented? If you're not using a gem for it, please post the relevant model code. Where does the `children` method come from?

Comment: I have updated the question with some code of the model. I'm also interested in writing better code without using an extra gem for this one.