# Should I use simple or polymorphic associations in this case? [Rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, polymorphic-associations

Suppose I want to build something like tumblr, a kind of blog in which a post can be one of many kinds of content (text, quote, image, link, etc).

Is it ok for me to use simple associations, such as...

```
Class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :quotes
  has_many :images
  has_many :links
etc

Class Quote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :blog
end

Class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :blog
etc
```

Or do I have to use polymorphic associations? If so, what would it look like? If it's indifferent, what are the pros and cons of each approach?

Answer (score 2):

In your example I would recommend you to use Single Table Inheritance

[Single table inheritance and where to use it in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555668/single-table-inheritance-and-where-to-use-it-in-rails)

You have one entity with different types that have common behavior - it is exactly what STI was created for.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was not familiar with STI. However, from what I read, it seems STI is a good solution for when the types share the same attributes, which is not my case. Even using the example, for example, `Quote` would have `excerpt` and `author`, while `Link` would have `url` and `title`, etc. There's really not a lot of overlap. I couldn't find information on how to handle STI in this case.