# Rails: similar classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, oop, inheritance

I'm creating a message-board website using Rails. I have a `Topic` class and `Post` class.
it is easy to notice the similarity between the two classes (content, title, user_id..)

what is the best practice in Rails with this scenario? 
should `Topic` inherit from `Post`? how does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Module Mixins**: just include this module on any class

**Inheritance (STI)**: you have to use the same table for those classes

**Polymorphic**: you have to use a different tables for each class

In my opinion, its really hard to answer *in general* what is the best practice, since it really depends on the situation--in some cases you may even want to use a combination, god forbid.

I would stick with **Module Mixins** because its simple and flexible.  If you think you'll be *double writing* queries a lot because you have two separate tables, then try **Inheritance (STI)**.  From experience, definitely **Polymorphic** can be a *headache, with a ton of gotchas* if your not familiar, so probably not worth it for 2 classes.

```
# Heres one way to set up Inheritance (STI) on a table called 'contents'
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :content, :title
    belongs_to :user
end

class Topic < Content
end

class Post < Content
end

Content.all             # => query topics and posts
#Post.all + Topic.all   # => query topics and posts without STI (doublewriting query)

Post.all    # => only query posts
Topic.all   # => only  topics
```

*General Rails best practice?*  **K** eep **I** t **S** imple **S** tupid

Answer (score 3):

For the most part, it depends. If these have a very similar table structure and / or duplicate methods I would go with STI. However, if the classes have different foreign keys I usually don't use this approach.

On the other hand if these have a few common traits, but the classes them selves are different enough I would extract the common code into a module (basically a mixin).
If you need more flexibility you may want to use a [concern](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) or even extract common patterns into a gem.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest looking into [Single-Table Inheritance (STI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_Table_Inheritance), which allows you to have multiple models share the same database table, differentiated by a `type` column.

A few articles on the topic I just found with a quick search:

- [Single table inheritance and where to use it in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555668/single-table-inheritance-and-where-to-use-it-in-rails)
- [Single Table Inheritance in Rails 3](http://blog.thirst.co/post/14885390861/rails-single-table-inheritance)
- [Single Table Inheritance with Rails](http://therailworld.com/posts/18-Single-Table-Inheritance-with-Rails)
- [Single Table Inheritance in Rails](http://code.alexreisner.com/articles/single-table-inheritance-in-rails.html)