# rails: create scaffold for models to inherit from superclass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model, scaffolding

I'm new to Rails, still getting my feet wet, so please pardon me if this is either trivial or "the wrong way" to do things.

I'd like to create a superclass for some scaffolded models.  For example, I'd like to create a scaffold for `Men` and for `Women`, but I want them both to inherit from a `People` superclass; `Men` and `Women` would inherit fields like `height` and `weight` from the `People` class.

Where/how do I define this `People` superclass?  How do I define the subclasses `Men` and `Women` via scaffolding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is something I've thought about doing with my application. I haven't done it yet, and I wouldn't recommend it if you are new to rails. I would either make separate models entirely, or make one model, and have the attribute `gender`, which should be either a 0 or a 1, and then make a method that returns the string for the corresponding gender.

**EDIT**

So I opened up the rails console, and from what I could see, it is possible totally possible, all you need to do is declare the class, and if you want to use different tables, `set_table_name`

```
class This < That
  set_table_name :this
end

class There < This
   set_table_name :there
end
```

Or you could use one table, but if your trying to stay DRY, I would use two.

If you want to use the scaffold generator, you will have to run the typical `rails g scaffold Men` for each class you want views for (men and women). The model that this generates inherits from the `ActiveRecord::Base` class. The inheritance marker is the less than symbol (`<`).

```
# THESE WILL BE THE DEFAULT GENERATED MODELS
class Men < ActiveRecord::Base

end

class Women < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

You will then manually create the super class `User`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

and then edit the `Men` and `Women` models to inherit from `User`

```
# men.rb
class Men < User
end

# women.rb
class Women < User
end
```

lets say you wanted to subclass with one table, you could would right the migrations for that table, and then add the `attr_accessible` to the appropriate subclass.

`attr_accessible` is a rails security feature. It determines which attributes may be set in mass assignment. Anything related to security, site rank, etc. should not be accessible.

Example:

```
attr_accessible :favorite_food, :interests, :password, :email # THIS IS GOOD

attr_accessible :admin, :has_access_to_missile_launch_codes # THIS IS BAD
```

because then someone could undermine your security system by passing

`params => { :man => { :admin => true }}`

The main point is that using these `attr_accessible` will determine which type of user can set what. Obviously you can DRY this up by putting shared features in the super-class. Hope this helps

You should also read about the `super` keyword, and the `self` keyword. If your running an inherited setup you will eventually want to use these.

Comment: Yep, you're probably right for this trivial example.  But what if I want to track information specific to each gender?  Like, if I want establish a "moustache_style" field for Men, but not for Women?  Obviously this is a contrived example, but for even a little more elaborate models, it will be hard to keep things DRY and relevant.

Comment: OK, I see your point, I should've known you were using placeholder classes. I never give info about my application on SO. I'll run some tests and get back to you.

Comment: I'm still learning how things fit together; I'm happy it can work, but I'm not sure where to declare these classes.  Do I create two scaffolds from the command line as usual ("Men" and "Women"), then manually edit the generated code to inherit from the "People" class?  Where do I declare the "People" class (the "That" class in your example)?

Comment: Great, this is what I was looking for.  Let me test it out and I'll get back to you.  Thanks!

Comment: Cool, remember, this could be considered `bleeding edge` and may not be compatible with some popular gems. And don't forget to accept the correct answer!

Comment: I won't forget.  I think this makes sense as far as it goes, and I can edit my code manually to reflect the inheritance after the scaffold runs.  The trouble is with the database and migrations; I feel like I'm getting over my head here.  http://blog.thirst.co/post/14885390861/rails-single-table-inheritance

Comment: this is why I would use the `set_table_name` method to use two tables. I think that that is the best solution, however lets say you wanted to subclass with one table, you could would right the migrations for that table, and then add the attributes to the appropriate subclass

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the right answer.  Made you work for it. :) Thanks very much!  Although note: set_table_name is apparently deprecated as of Rails 3.2, in favor of self.table_name

Answer (score 7):

Usually I do something like:

```
rails g scaffold People type:string name:string birth:date height:integer

class People < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Important use the reserved word 'type'! That's where the table will keep which type the class is. Run the migration.

So, for the the subclasses you can do:

```
rails g scaffold Men --parent=People
```

resulting Men:

```
class Men < People
end
```

Same for Women:

```
rails g scaffold Women --parent=People
```

Resulting

```
class Women < People
end
```

No migration will be generated for the subclasses.
I'm not sure but this approach only works for STI.

Hope it, helps!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you'd need to tweak the existing scaffolding templates, I don't believe there's a means to specify the controller base class. That said, I think in Rails 3 you can copy the templates into `$ROOT/lib/templates/rails/...` where `...` depends on which you want to change.

That said, what's the real goal in doing this in a scaffold? In general, models will (a) only rarely be subclasses, and (b) even more rarely be the *same* subclass.

Just edit them by hand.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not entirely sure whether a scaffold is necessary; it's basically an exercise.  I'm trying to apply OOP concepts to Rails: testing it conceptually, learning how to model things.  I know Ruby can do this; in Rails, however, there may be a better approach.  Anyways, where can I find those scaffold templates?

Answer (score 0):

watch this screencast on single table inheritance.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/394-sti-and-polymorphic-associations

---

[Single table inheritance and where to use it in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/555668/single-table-inheritance-and-where-to-use-it-in-rails)