# How to refactor method that occurs in multiple models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, model, refactoring

I have a method that is repeated in multiple models. Should I just repeat this code in multiple models or is there a way to include the method in 1 place and make it available to multiple models?

```
  # Returns true if the given token matches the digest.
  def authenticated?(attribute, token)
    digest = send("#{attribute}_digest")
    return false if digest.nil?
    BCrypt::Password.new(digest).is_password?(token)
  end
```

Comment: Try using concerns. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll be best using a `concern`, although in theory you could also use a [`superclass`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/inheritance.html):

---

[**Concerns**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html)

This is standard Rails functionality:

```
#app/models/concerns/auth.rb
module Auth
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def authenticated?(attribute, token)
     digest = send("#{attribute}_digest")
     return false if digest.nil?
     BCrypt::Password.new(digest).is_password?(token)
  end
end
```

Then you just have to include `auth` in your model:

```
#app/models/your_model.rb
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
   include Auth
end
```

[Excellent writeup here](https://richonrails.com/articles/rails-4-code-concerns-in-active-record-models)

---

**Superclass**

Another way would be to create a "superclass".

This will be hacky (because it's populating the ActiveRecord method chain with another model), but could be interesting to try.

```
#app/models/auth.rb
class Auth < ActiveRecord::Base
   def authenticate?
     ....
   end
end

#app/models/user.rb
class User < Auth
   self.table_name = self.model_name.plural
end
```

Being honest, this method seems hacky, although it will allow you to extend model functionality much more than a `concern` would.

Refs:

- [table_name](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ModelSchema/ClassMethods/table_name)
- [rails: create scaffold for models to inherit from superclass?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15853334/rails-create-scaffold-for-models-to-inherit-from-superclass)