# Rails STI on nested model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, single-table-inheritance

I have a question about STI in rails that I cannot seem to get my head around.

I have 2 models, `order.rb`

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :answers
end
```

and `answer.rb`

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :order
    attr_accessible :value, :input_id, :type
end
```

`answer.rb` also has a couple of STI classes like `select.rb`

```
class Select < Answer
    validates presence: true
end
```

The reason for this is that I want to be able to make custom validations and caluclations on different types of answers.

Everything works ok until I'm trying to make a fields_for on answers that is associated to each order. I am abled to instiate each STI class when rendering the form. All of the answers will however end up in the array `answers_attributes` when the form is submitted and will all be considered as `class Answer` instead of for example `class Select`.

Anyone got some idea on how I might solve this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I get your problem right, but maybe you are looking for `becomes`?

```
Answer.last.becomes(Select)
```

Comment: Hmm, the problem is that some of the STI classes has dynamic attributes through attr_accessor that are rendered in the form and then parsed into value in the STI model. So I think I need them to be in their STI class when posting the form.

Comment: You might want to check [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/555668/single-table-inheritance-and-where-to-use-it-in-rails)