# Model without attributes for has_many :through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, database-design, model

Consider the following I have messages that should be coupled together by thread. I have ended up with an architecture like this: `Message` belongs_to `Thread` and `Thread` has_many `Messages`. The key point here is to have an ability to get all related messages to the one i am working with.

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :body      
  belongs_to :thread
  has_many :messages, through: :thread


end

class Thread < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages
end
```

However I am a bit concerned about having a blank model. Model named `Thread` does not have any meaningful attributes in it. It is just a table with primary key sequence.

I had and idea to turn it into a tree but it looks too heavy too.

What do you think about it? How do you organize several models together with one blank model?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need thread table? I recommend you should use single table inheritance. Add

```
parent_message_id
```

in your messages table and get all the messages of a same thread using this id

Comment: Hi @Abk Can you write down the query to show user message history?

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/555668/single-table-inheritance-and-where-to-use-it-in-rails)